# Bounce MIDI file to ringtone: AVFoundation, AudioQueue, AudioUnits or FluidSynth?

Tags: ios8, avfoundation, core-audio

I am writing an iOS8 app that generates a MIDI file, then plays it with AVMIDIPlayer.
Which is the simplest (i.e.: highest-level) way to add a reverb to the result and to bounce all to a ringtone file?
Is there a way to do this in AVFoundation, should I go with an Audio Queue, should I dig into Audio Units, or use a non-Apple solution like FluidSynth?

Thanks!

Comment: I am working with AudioQueue to do something similar. It is simple, but may not be the simplest...

Comment: After some months spent on it, I think that the reverb already included in the soundfonts will be enough. So no need to go further, on my side.
Good luck with your project!